# *SOLVED* CHAINLINK VRF V2 Not Invoking Callback fulfillRandomWords()

Tags: solidity, chainlink, vrf

I have the following code that is deployed using REMIX Injected Web3 into AVALANCHE FUJI TESTNET

```
import '@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/VRFCoordinatorV2Interface.sol';
import '@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFConsumerBaseV2.sol';

contract ULotto is VRFConsumerBaseV2{

VRFCoordinatorV2Interface COORDINATOR;

    //values for CHAIN Link Integration
    uint64 s_subscriptionId; 
    address vrfCoordinator = 0x2eD832Ba664535e5886b75D64C46EB9a228C2610;
    bytes32 s_keyHash = 0x354d2f95da55398f44b7cff77da56283d9c6c829a4bdf1bbcaf2ad6a4d081f61;
    uint32 callbackGasLimit = 2000000;
    uint16 requestConfirmations = 3;
    uint32 numWords = 6;
    uint256[] public s_results;

constructor(uint64 subscriptionId) VRFConsumerBaseV2(vrfCoordinator){
        owner = msg.sender;
        lotteryIdCounter = 1;

        COORDINATOR = VRFCoordinatorV2Interface(vrfCoordinator);
        s_subscriptionId = subscriptionId;
    }

function fulfillRandomWords(uint256 requestId, uint256[] memory randomWords) internal override {
        s_results = randomWords;
    }

    function drawNumbers() public onlyOwner returns (uint256 requestId){
        //dragons require logic here

        requestId = COORDINATOR.requestRandomWords(
            s_keyHash,
            s_subscriptionId,
            requestConfirmations, 
            callbackGasLimit,
            numWords
        );

    }

}
```

When I call draw numbers, I can see from testnet.snowtrace.io/ that the callback to my function has error.

[image]
[image]
[image: Internal TXNs of supposed callback]

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Hey there. Have you remembered to add the address of the contract as a consumer in the VRF subscription console?

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks for your comment. Yes, everytime I deploy the contract, I add it as a consumer. I make sure as well that the subscriptionId matches the one on the console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things to check with issues like this.

1. Check that the Contract is a consumer in the VRF Subscription, as Richard Horrocks mentioned above
2. Double check you supplied the correct subscription ID to the contract
3. Try running the `fulfillRandomWords` function to see what the gas requirement is. Often the `callbackGasLimit` will need to be increased if the logic in the callback is involved.

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks for this answer. I can confirm #1 and #2 are correct. How would I run fulfillRandomWords function?

Answer (score 2):

To anyone who might view this question in the future.

As a summary, you need to follow the feedback of the 2 Richards who responded.

An important thing to consider is how you process the randomWords. Try to make the contents of `fulfillRandomWords()` as simple as you can, possibly just saving the `uint256[] randomWords`. I had loops to process the response on mine and I think that's what was causing the transaction to either `out of gas` or `revert`.